# Mysql Error when do mysql_real_escape_string on a multiple line query

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

When I have a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM aii_images
WHERE id=34
```

and do mysql_real_escape_string on it i got:

```
Something is wrong in your syntax near '\n                FROM aii_images
```

There is no such problem when not using mysql_real_escape_string.

Is there a good way to fix it? 
Str_replace, or similar functions are not an option - my queries sometimes contain "\n" and also lots of text. Str_replace would kill my server.

Comment: can you post more than just the sql query? the implementation would be nice to see. ``mysql_real_escape_string()`` is used for values to be escaped, not for the entire query. Think about __prepared statements__ (--> http://www.php.net/PDO)

Comment: did you hit `Enter` after `SELECT *` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` only with values, not with the whole statement.

```
$strStatement = "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        aii_images
    WHERE
        id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $strId ) . "';";
```

Comment: Note that in this example, if `$strId` did contain a malicious value that required escaping, the lack of quotes around the value in query would result in a SQL error. It would prevent the hack, but it would also break your code. You need to add quotes around it to be completely protected.

Comment: Thx, I think I will have to do this. I thought it's possible to "escape string" in every query.

Comment: @SDC your right, i forgot them because i use `PDO::quote()` and there quotes are not needed. I add the quotes to my answer. Shame on me! :-D

Comment: @Raisch - I guess that leads on to the real answer, which is "use PDO, not mysql_xxx functions". (see my answer)

Comment: @SDC - I agree with that. @user1410263 - Use `PDO` with _Prepared Statements_ => see: [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're not supposed to escape the *whole* query; just the fields that you're inserting. (see @Raisch's answer for this)

Secondly, it is recommended not to use the `mysql_xxx` functions any more -- The PHP manual states this very clearly: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Instead, you should be using either the `mysqli_xxx` functions, or the PDO library. See the link above for further links to more information and to the manual pages for those two libraries.

If you're using either of those libraries, you can use the "Prepared Statements" technique, which frees you up from ever having to manually escape your strings again. This is much better technique, and would render this entire question redundant.